# In Windows NDIS's passthru example, how to send a NDIS_PACKET with a specific adapter?

Tags: c++, windows, device-driver, ndis

I'm working on a NAT-like software in Windows platform by modifying the original passthru example in Windows WDK.

Here're several network adapters in my machine, and I wanna analyze every packet I received then decide which adapter to forward the packet to.
There comes the problem: I don't know how to specify the adapter for sending when calling the NdisSend function.

As follows, there's a BindingHandle arg in NdisSend, but in my understanding it should stand for all the adapters in passthru(may not right:)

NdisSend(&Status, pAdapt->BindingHandle, MyPacket);

So how to specify a adapter like this form :{62E9DB05-88D3-479D-A194-22D6A591DB96} when calling NdisSend?

Very thx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the clue is `pAdapt->BindingHandle`, so `pAdapt` is a pointer to a structure that contains all adapter-specific information, including a `BindingHandle`.  So each adapter has a different `BindingHandle`, and that's how you control which adapter gets the packet.

Also you might want to investigate if you can use WFP instead of NDIS for you driver.

Comment: Now I know one pAdapt stands for adapter in my machine, which can satisfy my requirement. The WFP you mentioned can support XP and Win7 simultaneously? Because there're many people still using XP in my country..